# I have Problems with MyGraph Properties Vertices names , and Edges weight

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

in MyGraphBuilder Class I'm facing some Problems During My Implementation of the Graph property assignment:

1. ```
    G:\QT\Projects\My Project\boost\graph\detail\adjacency_list.hpp:2700: error: forming reference to void
    typedef value_type& reference;
   ```
2. ```
     G:\QT\Projects\MY Project\boost\graph\dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:588: error: no matching function for call to 'choose_const_pmap(const type&, const boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertProperty, EdgeProperty>&, boost::edge_weight_t)'
   choose_const_pmap(get_param(params, edge_weight), g, edge_weight),
   ```

Also When I used The Print Function to just Print The Count of Nodes and Edges, it Counted Nodes Only, but the Count of Edges Showed '0' can you tell me what is the problem please ?

#### Header File:

```
#ifndef MYGRAPHBUILDER_H
#define MYGRAPHBUILDER_H

// Generic Libraries
//===============================================
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

// Boost Libraries
//===============================================
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
// MyColleague Libraries
//===============================================
#include <modelDataStructure.h>
#include <modelDataHandler.h>
#include <modeldata.h>
#include <model.h>
// Osmium Libraries
//===============================================
#include <osmium/osm.hpp>
#include <osmium/index/map/flex_mem.hpp>
#include <osmium/visitor.hpp>
#include <osmium/osm/location.hpp>
#include <osmium/osm/node_ref.hpp>
//===============================================
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
//===============================================
typedef osmium::unsigned_object_id_type idType ;
typedef map<idType, wayData> WayMap;//Define map of Ways ans Their ID
//==================================================
struct VertProperty
{
  idType id;
  osmium::Location loc;
};

struct EdgeProperty
{
  double length;
};

typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, directedS,VertProperty,EdgeProperty > graph_t;
typedef graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_descriptor Vertex; // Vertex declaration
typedef graph_traits < graph_t >::edge_descriptor Edge; // Edge as link between two Nodes specified by ID
//==================================================

class MyGraphBuilder
{
private:               // This Line is Useless just for clarity
  graph_t MyGraph;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public:
  MyGraphBuilder(); // default Constructor
  MyGraphBuilder(Model); // Parameters Constructor
  ~MyGraphBuilder(); // Destructor
  double Distance(idType,idType); // function to calculate the distance between 2 Verices
  //===============================================
  //Accessors
  // function to get the Graph
  graph_t getGraph();
  //===============================================
  // Mutators
  void setGraph(graph_t);
   //===============================================
  void printGraph() const;
  //friend class MyAlgorithm;
};//end of the Class
/////////////////////////////////////
#endif // MYGRAPHBUILDER_H
```

#### CPP File

```
// Generic Libraries
//===============================================
#include <math.h>
// Belal Libraries
//===============================================
#include <mygraphbuilder.h>
// Boost Libraries
//===============================================
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
MyGraphBuilder::MyGraphBuilder() // default Constructor
{
  Model OurModel;
  WayMap MyWayMap = OurModel.getWayMap();
  WayMap::iterator it;
  // it->first  ;// (key = WayID)
  // it->second ;// (Value WayData.nodRefList[idType])
  for ( it = MyWayMap.begin(); it != MyWayMap.end(); it++ ) // Loop the Whole Way Map
    {
      unsigned int NodesOfWayIndex = 0; //define Index
      idType VertixID; // define Variable to Store Vertix Index
      vector<Vertex> WayNodes(it->second.nodeRefList.size());//define a vector of nodes with size of Way
      for(auto j = it->second.nodeRefList.begin(); j != it->second.nodeRefList.end(); ++j){// Loop The Whole Nodes of Each way
          VertixID = it->second.nodeRefList.at(NodesOfWayIndex);
          //VertixID added as Bundeled property name to the vertex
          Vertex v = *vertices(MyGraph).first;
          Edge e = *edges(MyGraph).first;
          //=======================================================
          MyGraph[v].id = VertixID;
          MyGraph[v].loc = OurModel.getNodeLoaction(VertixID);
          //=======================================================
          WayNodes[NodesOfWayIndex] = VertixID;
          if(NodesOfWayIndex != 0) {
              MyGraph[e].length = Distance(WayNodes[NodesOfWayIndex - 1], WayNodes[NodesOfWayIndex]);
            }
        }
      NodesOfWayIndex++;
    }
  cout<<"\n\n Graph Was Built ...\n\n";
}
//===========================================================================
MyGraphBuilder::MyGraphBuilder(Model OurModel){  // Parameters Constructor
   WayMap MyWayMap = OurModel.getWayMap();
   WayMap::iterator it;
   // it->first  ;// (key = WayID)
   // it->second ;// (Value WayData.nodRefList[idType])
   for ( it = MyWayMap.begin(); it != MyWayMap.end(); it++ ) // Loop the Whole Way Map
     {
       unsigned int NodesOfWayIndex = 0; //define Index
       idType VertixID; // define Variable to Store Vertix Index
       vector<Vertex> WayNodes(it->second.nodeRefList.size());//define a vector of nodes with size of Way
       for(auto j = it->second.nodeRefList.begin(); j != it->second.nodeRefList.end(); ++j){// Loop The Whole Nodes of Each way
           VertixID = it->second.nodeRefList.at(NodesOfWayIndex);
           //VertixID added as Bundeled property name to the vertex
           Vertex v = *vertices(MyGraph).first;
           Edge e = *edges(MyGraph).first;
           //=======================================================
           MyGraph[v].id = VertixID;
           MyGraph[v].loc = OurModel.getNodeLoaction(VertixID);
           //=======================================================
           WayNodes[NodesOfWayIndex] = VertixID;
           if(NodesOfWayIndex != 0) {
               MyGraph[e].length = Distance(WayNodes[NodesOfWayIndex - 1], WayNodes[NodesOfWayIndex]);
             }
         }
       NodesOfWayIndex++;
     }
   cout<<"\n\n Graph Was Built ...\n\n";
 }

MyGraphBuilder::~MyGraphBuilder (){ // default Destructor

}

double MyGraphBuilder::Distance(idType Nod1_ID, idType Nod2_ID){ // Function to calculate Euclidean Distance between Vertices
  modelData*m_Data = new modelData;
  osmium::Location L1,L2; // define any 2 locations on earth
  L1 = m_Data->getNodeLoaction(Nod1_ID) ; // get first location
  L2 = m_Data->getNodeLoaction(Nod2_ID) ; // get second location
  double dist = 0; // distance
  double x1 = L1.lat(); // first location latitude
  double x2 = L2.lat(); // second location latitude
  double y1 = L1.lon(); // first location longitude
  double y2 = L2.lon(); // second location longitude
  dist = sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2)+pow((y1-y2),2));
  return dist;
}
// Accessors
graph_t MyGraphBuilder::getGraph(){
  return MyGraph;
}
// Mutators
void MyGraphBuilder::setGraph(graph_t YourGraph){
  MyGraphBuilder::MyGraph = YourGraph;
}
//=========================================
void MyGraphBuilder::printGraph()const{
  unsigned long long NodesCount = num_vertices(MyGraph);
  cout<<"Number of Vertices is :\t"<<NodesCount<<"\n";
  unsigned long long EdgesCount = num_edges(MyGraphBuilder::MyGraph);
  cout<<"Number of Edges is :\t"<<EdgesCount<<"\n";
  //for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(MyGraph))) {
  //    cout << "Nodes " << v << " name " << MyGraph[v].name << "\n";
  //        for (auto oe : make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, MyGraph))) {
  //           cout << "Edge " << oe << " weight " << MyGraph[oe].weight << "\n";
  //        }
  //    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of include files is that you do not have to repeat their contents in the translation unit that `#include`s it. Also, it looks like you should probably be including most of that in the cpp only, because it might only be implementation detail

Comment: @sehe I have got your advise about #includes and modefied CPP here due to it, also I added Bundled Properties thanks for your reference to the documentation  , thanks so much for that

Comment: What is in the include file `modelDataStructure.h` ?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland `#ifndef MODELDATASTRUCTURE_H
#define MODELDATASTRUCTURE_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <osmium/osm.hpp>
using namespace std;
using tagPair = pair<string,string>;
using idType = osmium::unsigned_object_id_type;
struct relationMember
{    osmium::item_type type;    idType ref;  string role;
};
struct relationData
{    vector<relationMember> memberList;    vector<tagPair> tagList;
};
struct nodeData
{    vector<tagPair> tagList;
};
struct wayData
{
    vector<idType> nodeRefList;    vector<tagPair> tagList;
};
#endif // MODELDATASTRUCTURE_H`

Comment: @BelalHomaidan In order for your question to be [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you need to include all missing files in your question. Also try to make it [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @@Håkon Hægland I had modified My Code Due to @sehe **sehe** nice advice , thanks to him, parts of My problem solved, but new problems appeared again !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    cout << "Nodes " << v << " name " << MyGraph[v].name << "\n";
```

This syntax asks for the `boost::vertex_bundle_t` property, but none exists.

From the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html):

> Class templates `adjacency_list` and `adjacency_matrix` support the introduction
>   of named properties via internal properties. However, this method is
>   cumbersome in many uses, where it would be more intuitive to just specify a
>   structure or class that contains internal properties for edges or vertices.
>   Bundled properties allow one to use `adjacency_list` and `adjacency_matrix` in
>   this manner, providing a simple way to introduce and access any number of
>   internal properties for vertices and edges.

Compare with [How can I solve this error in Printing Nodes and Edges Boost Graph Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974799/how-can-i-solve-this-error-in-printing-nodes-and-edges-boost-graph-library/58979234#58979234), where the vertex property type is a class. This is known as a "bundle property" and they're generally more user-friendly to use.

If you are using the older style of internal properties:

```
property<vertex_name_t, idType>
```

You need to access them using property-maps. You can use them with the `get` or `put` accessor methods:

```
boost::put(boost::vertex_name, MyGraph, 0, "one");
```

or grab a propertymap first:

```
auto name_pmap = boost::get(boost::vertex_name, MyGraph);
name_pmap[0] = "one";
```

Here's the same example from the previous answer but using internal properties instead of bundles:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e40e8d6624ab930)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using idType = std::string; // mock osmium stuff?

using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
      boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, idType>, 
      boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> >;

using boost::make_iterator_range;

class MyGraphBuilder {
    graph_t MyGraph;

  public:
    void generate();
    void printGraph() const;
};

#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
void MyGraphBuilder::generate() {
    std::mt19937 prng { 42 }; // fixed random seed
    generate_random_graph(MyGraph, 5, 5, prng);

    boost::put(boost::vertex_name, MyGraph, 0, "one");

    // or grab a propertymap first:
    auto name_pmap = boost::get(boost::vertex_name, MyGraph);
    name_pmap[0] = "one";
    name_pmap[1] = "two";
    name_pmap[2] = "three";
    name_pmap[3] = "four";
    name_pmap[4] = "five";

    auto weight_pmap = boost::get(boost::edge_weight, MyGraph);
    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(MyGraph))) {
        weight_pmap[e] = std::uniform_real_distribution<>(1.0, 10.0)(prng);
    }
}

void MyGraphBuilder::printGraph() const {
    std::cout << "Number of Vertices is:" << num_vertices(MyGraph) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number of Edges is:" << num_edges(MyGraph) << "\n";

    print_graph(MyGraph, get(boost::vertex_name, MyGraph), std::cout);

    // to print with edge weights:
    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(MyGraph))) {
        for (auto oe : make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, MyGraph))) {
            std::cout << "Edge " << oe << " weight " << boost::get(boost::edge_weight, MyGraph, oe) << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    MyGraphBuilder builder;

    builder.generate();
    builder.printGraph();
}
```

Printing:

```
Number of Vertices is:5
Number of Edges is:5
one --> 
two --> four 
three --> one one 
four --> three 
five --> one 
Edge (1,3) weight 1.52275
Edge (2,0) weight 8.79559
Edge (2,0) weight 6.41004
Edge (3,2) weight 7.37265
Edge (4,0) weight 1.18526
```

Comment: idType is Node ID from type unsigned long long, and it's not mock , because I need to use it to define a way between nodes, I can't use string, also I don't want generate random graph, I already have graph with function to calculate the distance between nodes, my problem is in assigning the idType which is (unsigned long long) to the Vertex as a property, so I can call it later when defining shortest path, also I failed assigning the edge property weight in this code, and I don't know how to build the Graph with my Nodes (idType) and Edges with distance.

Comment: I mocked the idType because obviously I don't have it. I used `std::string` to make the example work. The rest is all demonstrated in the code. The key point is that you had copied code from my answer that used the property bundle approach. Now you can copy likewise but using the `boost::property<>` approach that you were using in your own code apparently.

Comment: Note that all of this could have been avoided when your previous question had contained the graph type (so I didn't make up an example with a different property type) and when the code in the question is self-contained, I'll usually just copy/paste it and fix that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and http://sscce.org

Comment: Thanks for your Valuable advices, My Graph was built with Vertex names, and Edge Weights, but while using your cool function of printing the graph, I have noticed last edge in each way of my map (Way means Vector of sequenced Vertices) is connecting the Last Node With Nothing ! How Can I solve that ! `if(WayIndex != 0) { //This Condition to start from Second Node
              dist = Distance(WayNodes[WayIndex - 1], WayNodes[fWayIndex]);
              add_edge(WayVertices[WayIndex-1], WayVertices[WayIndex],dist,MyGraph);
     }`I'm looping through Way Vector using the common iterator